# Setting compression level in Imagick automatically to reach max file size

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am retrieving the size of images as they are uploaded Imagick:

```
$im->getImageSize();
```

This returns the size in bytes of the image.

I would like to set the compression level automatically so that the file size never goes above a certain size.  If I wanted to limit to 70kb with a minimum allowed compression level of 60 (on a scale of 0-100) I would start by doing something like this:

```
 public function getCompLevel($size)
 {
                    $maxsize = 70000; // Set rough max size of file
                    $mincomp = 60;   // Set minimum compression level allowed


                    if($size > $maxsize ){   // If file size exceeds max allowed size, perform calculation
                        $comp = **EQUATION**
                    }

        return ($comp < $mincomp) ? $mincomp : $comp; // if output is less than minimum allowed compression , return minimum.  If not return calculated compression level
 }
```

What I am trying to figure out is the equation needed to calculate a close approximation of the needed compression level based on the files size.  I understand this may not be all that accurate due to colours effecting file size, but I would like to get as close as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this question, although there is really no right answer. I have replicated multipule instances in which the variable `$x` would represent the file size starting at zero and would increase to double the maximum file size. Additionally, I have created a variable `$equalizer`. This variable works exponentially, whereas setting it to `100` will create a higher compression level, and alternatively the closer to `0` will create a much larger gap.

```
<?php
$max_file_size = 70000;
$max_compression = 60;
$equalizer = 100;

for($x=0;$x<$max_file_size+$max_file_size;$x+=10000){
    if($x < $max_file_size){
        echo $max_compression.'<br>';
    }else{
        echo $max_compression - (($x / $max_compression * $max_file_size) / ($max_file_size * $max_compression * $equalizer)).'<br>';
    }

}?>
```

In, your real world situation, I would imagine your function looking something like:

```
<?php
function getCompLevel($size){
    $maxsize = 70000;
    $compression = 60;
    $equalizer = 100;

    if($size > $maxsize ){
        $compression = $compression - (($size / $compression * $maxsize) / ($maxsize * $compression * $equalizer));
    }

    return $compression;
}?>
```

Comment: Unbelievable... This is exactly what I am looking for and appears to work pretty well.  A fantastic answer which completely covers the outline in its entirety.  Huge thanks Samuel!

Comment: I really liked this question, glad i could help